# condition inside another in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, netbeans, user-input

[let the user get 3 attempts only, after it he get his account suspened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4wje.jpg)I tried to ask the user to give a final password 3 times if he didn't it will give him that his account suspended and if it right gives him a grating message.

```
package EE;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            final String password= "Test";
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter the password: ");
            String pass = sc.next();
            for (int i=0; i<2;) {
            if (!pass.equals (password))
                i++;
                System.out.println("Try again! ");
                String pass1 = sc.next();
                     if(pass.equals( password))
                        System.out.println("Welcome");
                        String pass2 = sc.next();
                    if (i == 2)
            System.out.println("Sorry, your account is suspened");      
    }
}}
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you're asking about?

Comment: Use a loop, a while loop. Look it up and give it a shot.

Comment: Try to use brackets `{ }` in your if-statements. If you don't have any, it will only execute the next line after the if-statement

Comment: @alea could you be more specific, please? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alea commented, you need to use braces `{ ... }` around the blocks in your `if` statements:

```
for (int i=0; i<2;) {
if (!pass.equals (password))
    i++;
    System.out.println("Try again! ");
    String pass1 = sc.next();
         if(pass.equals( password))
            System.out.println("Welcome");
            String pass2 = sc.next();
        if (i == 2)
System.out.println("Sorry, your account is suspened");
}
```

actually means this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ) {
    if (!pass.equals(password)) {
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Try again! ");
    String pass1 = sc.next();
    if (pass.equals(password)) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }
    String pass2 = sc.next();
    if (i == 2) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your account is suspened");
    }
}
```

Once we have indented the code correctly and added the braces at the places where the compiler expects them, we can start to see some of the problems.

For example:

1. When the password is correct, nothing will increment `i`.  That means that `i < 2` won't be true, and the loop will keep going around, and around.
2. You are calling `next()` twice for each loop iteration.

And so on.

Now I *could* just rewrite your code for you<sup>1</sup>.  But you won't learn much from that.  (You will learn best by writing the code for yourself, making mistakes and finding and correcting them ... yourself!)

Instead I am going to recommend to you to read about the [Rubber Duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) technique.  This may sound like a joke, but it is not.  It is an important technique explained in a humorous way.  And it is what I was taught as a way debug programs, back when I was 18 years old learning to program<sup>2</sup>.

The idea behind Rubber Duck debugging is to help you understand how a computer "thinks".  Once you can do that, programming gets a lot easier.  And this is why I strongly recommend that you do this yourself!

Anyway, once you can visualize what the code is doing wrong, then next step is to work out what it *should* be doing.

---

<sup>1 - It would be quicker for, for a start!</sup>

<sup>2 - Though we didn't call it by that name back then.  We called it hand execution, and we did it with a pencil and paper.  Generally on the back of old computer printouts.  Yea, a long time ago.  And in those days, we didn't have debuggers or IDEs.  It was card punches and a 20 minute wait to get the printout back!</sup>

Comment: thanks, I Solve the problem and it was like you and @alea said, the braces.